# PDEs: Classical solutions and abstract differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to better understand the relationships between classical solutions for PDEs and for abstract differential equations. In particular, let us consider a very simple case: the transport equation
$$
u_t=u_x\qquad \forall (x,t)\in (0,1)\times\mathbb{R}_{>0}
$$ 
Let $u^\star\colon\mathcal{C}^1((0,1)\times\mathbb{R}_{>0};\mathbb{R})$ be a solution to the above PDE. Now, we know that the above PDE can be rewritten as the following abstract differential equation 
$$
\dot{u}=Au
$$
where $A\colon\mathcal{D}(A)\rightarrow\mathcal{C}^0((0,1);\mathbb{R})$ is the standard differential operator. Now, here is my question: Let $t\mapsto v(t)=u^\star(t,\cdot)$, where $u^\star$ is the solution to the above transport PDE, can one claim that for all $t\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, $\dot{v}(t)=Av(t)$?

Thanks!!

Comment: I don't see how changing the notation $u_t$ to $\dot{u}$ or $u_x$ to $Au$ makes a difference, assuming the latter notation is defined to coincide with the usually partial derivatives.  Perhaps you have in mind a different meaning, but saying "the standard differential operator" doesn't give Readers a lot of indication how the meaning is different.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Actually, what happens in the second writing is that the derivative with respect to $t$ is a Fréchet derivative, $u(t)$ being an element of a functional space for each $t$.

Comment: Okay, so in the sense that $A$ is being applied to $u(-,t)$ as a one-dimensional function of $x$, we are slightly abusing the notation.  Perhaps this is what you have in mind in describing the operator $A$  as a Fréchet derivative?

Comment: Right. But I don't see where I am abusing the notation. Provided that it is clear $A$ is an operator, then the notation should be quite standard.

Comment: Yes, provided the definition is clear this is quite proper.

Comment: Alright. I am glad my question is clear. Hopefully I will get some answers . Thanks.

Comment: This is exactly how weak solutions of time-dependent PDEs are interpreted (as, for example, elements of $C^1([0,T];X)$ for some Banach or Hilbert space $X$). When solutions are smooth, there is no difference.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you please provide more details and some references? Thanks!